# send each PDF file in separate email automatically using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email-attachments

I'd like to ask you for some help with my problem.
I'm trying to automate sending emails with attachement separately using VB

There is a folder with few PDF files to attache to the mail
the file name start with a code of 4 digits XXXX_*
this code is the one to use to get the email from the DATABASE and every time I try to send an email it sends for all the recipient all the files

```
Try
    Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
    Dim e_mail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()


    Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)
    Smtp_Server.Port = 587
    Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
    Smtp_Server.Host = TextBox1.Text
    e_mail = New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    e_mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text)
    'get users emails 

    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT EMail , code FROM [SagePaieSQL].[dbo].[T_SAL]  WHERE EMail IS NOT NULL and MatriculeSalarie   IS NOT NULL"

    Dim dir As String = "C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\fiche_de_ paie\"
    Dim output As New List(Of String)()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqLdr As SqlDataReader
    Dim dr As DataRow
    ConnServer()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = SQL
    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Using ds As New DataTable()
            sda.Fill(ds)
            sqLdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            For i = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1
                dr = ds.Rows(i)
                Console.WriteLine(i)
                e_mail.To.Add(dr("EMail").ToString())
                e_mail.Subject = TextBox6.Text
                e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                e_mail.Body = (TextBox7.Text)
                Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, dr("code") & "_*")
                If files.Any = False Then
                    MsgBox("bulltin non trouver ")
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    Button1.Enabled = False
                    For Each file As String In files
                        Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
                        Dim attach As New Net.Mail.Attachment(file)
                        e_mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
                        If e_mail.Attachments.Any = True Then
                            MsgBox("file attached")
                            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
                            MsgBox("Mail Sent")

                        Else
                            MsgBox("bulltin non attacher ")
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

Catch error_t As Exception
    MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: Why are you using `For Each` ?

Comment: Instead of making one `MailMessage`, you should make a new one inside the `For i = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1` loop. That way, you don't get all the previous recipients included in each email.

Comment: to find all the files that starting with the same code

Comment: @S.Taha Is there more than one file for each code? Becasue `For Each` loop sending all the files to every recipients. Instead find only correct file and use like `files[0]`